# (C++ OOP) Why name[] is not changing when I assign its pointer to a new value?

Tags: c++, oop

I am new to C++ OOP concepts and I come from a Java OOP background. I have tried `this->name=name` but I get an error and then I tried to use a pointer, but, even though the code runs, it does not 'save' the name in the object's name.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class Person{
private:
    char name[];
    int age;
public:
    Person(char name[], int age){
        char* pName=this->name;
        pName=name;

        this->age=age;
        cout<<this->name;
    }
    getInformation(){
        cout<<"name: "<<this->name<<" age: "<<this->age;
    }

};

int main(){
Person foo("foo",5);
}
```

Comment: This code is not valid and should not compile for multiple reasons. Starting from `char name[];` class member declaration being invalid. You should read some good C++ tutorials on arrays / pointers.

Comment: If `pName` is changed to point to `name`, that does not affect `this->name`.

Comment: What is it you are trying to do where you set `char* pName = this->name;` and then set `pName = name`?

Comment: You need to post the code that _runs_ since that is what you are asking about.  This code does not compile, so implicitly is not the code you are asking about.  Member arrays without dimensions (flexible array members) may only appear as the last member of a class/struct (but is not in any case what you need here).  `getInformation()` has no specified return type (should be `void`), and you are passing the string _constant_ "foo" to a non-const argument (which elicits a warning).

Comment: It would probably be more comprehensible to you, given your Java experience to use `std::string` rather then C char array strings.

Comment: Arrays are not pointers and pointers are not arrays.

Answer (score 0):

In C++, arrays usually need to be declared with a length - in this case, `char name[]` would be invalid.

Additionally, arrays declared `int array[5]` (with a size) cannot be directly assigned to. i.e. this is invalid:

```cpp
class A
{
public:
    int array[5];

    void foo() {
        int other_array[5] = {0, 0, 0, 0, 0};
        this->array = other_array;
    }
}
```

Instead, you need to assign each element one at a time (e.g. in a loop):

```cpp
for(int i = 0; i < 5; ++i) this->array[i] = other_array[i];
```

This is because in C++ arrays have space for all the elements, unlike Java where `char name[]` is a pointer to an array. If you want to be able to directly change what array a variable refers to, you should use a pointer instead - a pointer can be dereferenced like an array:

```cpp
class A
{
public:
    int *array;

    int foo(int *other_array) {
        this->array = other_array;
    }
}
```

Though if you do this, be careful of memory management.

Answer (score 0):

Ignoring (for the moment) the fact that the code is invalid and won't compile; here:

```
    char* pName=this->name;
```

You instantiate a *local pointer* and assign the *unitialised pointer* `name` to it.  Then you immediately reassign it with a pointer to the *parameter* `name`:

```
    pName=name;
```

But both `pName` and `name` are temporary and are *pointers* to strings, not the strings themselves.  Moreover `pName` is not a *reference* to `this->name`.  So on return from the `Person()` constructor, the object remains unchanged (and uninitialised).  You may have intended:

```
    char*& pName = this->name ;
    pName = name ;
```

But that is simply a convoluted form of:

```
    this->name = name ;
```

and is still ill advised because you are then assigning `this->name` with the address of the literal string `"foo"` from `main()` which is `const`.  In any case you are giving `Person` a pointer to data that belongs to something else and is not "owned" by `Person`, and `Person` has no knowledge of the data's lifetime or validity. It is  recipe for all kinds of bugs and undesired behaviour.

Null-terminated (or ASCIZ or C-style) strings are not a true data type; it is merely a char array convention.  Moreover arrays even are not first-class data types in C++ and you cannot assign one array to another or pass an array *by value* as a function argument - instead assignment and argument passing are *pointer operations*. In `Person()`, `name` is a pointer to the first character in the string constant `"foo"` not an independent string containing `"foo"`.

To correct this using C-style strings:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>

class Person
{
    private:
        char name[256];   // << Must have size here.
        int age;

    public:
        Person( const char* name, int age)   // << Must have const arg for "foo" to be a valid parameter.
        {
            std::strncpy( this->name,        // << C strings must be explicitly copied, not "assigned".
                          name, 
                          sizeof(this->age) - 1 ) ;
            this->age = age;
        }

        void getInformation() const   // << must have return type, and may be const.
        {
            std::cout << "name: " << this->name << " age: " << this->age << "\n" ;
        }

} ;
```

However in most cases it would be preferable to use C++ `std::string` objects:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>      // << Use C++ string library 
                       //    (i.e. string rather than cstring/string.h)

class Person
{
    private:
        std::string name;     // << std::string memory management is intrinsic
        int age;

    public:
        Person( const std::string name, int age)
        {
            this->name = name ;  // << Assignment possible due to
                                 //    operator overloading
            this->age = age;
        }

        void getInformation() const
        {
            std::cout << "name: " << this->name << " age: " << this->age << "\n" ;
        }

} ;
```

Answer (score 0):

As said above, std::string is to recommend for now.
Not only for this problem, std::string is very nice to work with in many cases. especially in the learningface.

Just take a look at the string class here from MS' site:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/standard-library/basic-string-class?view=vs-2019

Answer (score -2):

If you're using `c++`, it's way better to use `std::string` to deal with strings.
But answring to your question, when you assign a value to any variable, it overrides its previous value and gets a new one.

In your code:

```
char* pName=this->name;
pName=name;
```

The first line assigns a new value to your `pName` variable. and the second line, simply overrides your first line, and copies something new into your `pName` variable. so, that's not a correct approach for what you want to do.

If you want to have a `char *` variable and copy content of another `char *` into it, I suggest something like:

```
private:
    char *name;
    ...
public:
    Person(char name[], int age){
        this->name = strdup(name);
        ...
    }
```

And be careful to free memory of `name` in your destructor function.

Comment: This requires memcpy to be used in order to copy actual data. Also dynamic memory management.

Comment: @TarekDakhran but `strdup` exactly does that. it gets memory for the duplicated string. [link](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/strdup-strdndup-functions-c/)